# Looking for example of integral transformations that preserve number of zeros

Tags: real-analysis, integral-transforms, differential-calculus, integral-kernel

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ have $n<\infty$ zeros.
I am looking for non-trivial examples of integral transformation 
\begin{align}
g(x)= \int f(t) h(t,x) dt 
\end{align}
such that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros. Note that positions of zeros are allowed to change.

**Edit:**
Suppose we assume the following regularity conditions on $f$

1. $k$ times differentiable
2. $f$ is absolutely integrable   (i.e., $\int |f(x)| dx <\infty$)

Note: please feel free to add or change these assumptions. The point here is to see some meaningful examples.

Comment: What do you assume about functions $f$, $g$ and $h$? For most of the continuous functions $f$ the integral will not converge so $g$ and $f$ cannot have the same number of zeroes because $g$ would not even exist. You need to be more clear about the assumptions.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz Ok. I will add some regularity conditions for $f$.

Comment: I doubt there are non-trivial transformations that really *preserve* the number of zeroes, but there are many of them that do not increase this number. An example: $h(t,x) = e^{-(t-x)} \mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}(t - x)$. Try searching for "variation diminishing transform" and "Pólya frequency function" for more, if this answers your question at least partially.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki  Thank you. This is very good direction.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki  Also, are there integral transforms that increase the number of zeros by say at most $m$